# orphanRemoval JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring

Como funciona o orphanRemoval?

por que quando eu coloco ele em uma lista não funciona ex:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "simulationMedia", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<SimulationChemicalMedia> simulationChemicalMedias = new ArrayList<SimulationChemicalMedia>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OrphanRemoval está presente na maioria das anotações de relacionamento entre entidades, e que serve para definir a forma como uma ação de remoção atribuída a um objeto terá impacto sobre os objetos relacionados.

O OrphanRemoval marca entidades "filhas" para serem excluídas quando não tem qualquer outro vinculo com uma entidade pai, por exemplo, quando você tem um carro em uma lista de carros relacionados a um concessionária. Se a concessionária for excluída, caso o carro não tenha vínculo com outras concessionárias será excluído também.