# JPA object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Ao tentar salvar os "Enderecos" de "Cliente" o JPA/Spring me retorna o seguinte erro no "main"

> Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.nelioalves.cursomc.domain.Endereco.cidade -> com.nelioalves.cursomc.domain.Cidade

O código está assim:

```
    Cliente cli1 = new Cliente(null, "Maria Silva", "maria@gmail.com", "36378912377", TipoCliente.PESSOAFISICA);

    cli1.getTelefones().addAll(Arrays.asList("27363323", "93838393"));

    Endereco e1 = new Endereco(null, "Rua Flores", "300", "Apto 303", "Jardim", "38220834", cli1, c1);
    Endereco e2 = new Endereco(null, "Avenida Matos", "105", "Sala 800", "Centro", "38777012", cli1, c2);

    cli1.getEnderecos().addAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));

    enderecoRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
    clienteRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(cli1));
```

Ao retirar o endereço e salvar somente o cliente ele salva normalmente.

Eis a classe `Endereco`:

```
@Entity
public class Endereco {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String logradouro;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String cep;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cliente_id")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cidade_id")
    private Cidade cidade;

    public Endereco() {
    }
```

Eis a classe `Cliente`:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String cpfOuCnpj;
    private Integer tipo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente")
    private List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="TELEFONE")
    private Set<String> telefones = new HashSet<>();

    public Cliente() {
    }
```

Comment: Olá, coloque o código na pergunta e não os links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O erro TransientPropertyValueException ocorre quando você está persistindo um objeto que faz referência à um outro que não está persistido. No caso ao salvar o Endereco o seu objeto Cidade ainda não foi salvo.

Para corrigir salve a referência da cidade ou modifique a anotação @ManyToOne adicionando o parâmento cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST para que a cidade seja salva no momento que o endereço for salvo.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="cidade_id")
private Cidade cidade;
```

Você pode ver os tipos de cascade neste link [Quais são os tipos de cascade no JPA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193412/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-tipos-de-cascade-no-jpa)

Comment: Obrigado, fui verificar a cidade do segundo endereço não havia sido salva, por isso o erro

Comment: Solução perfeita

Answer (score 4):

Tente trocar isso na sua classe `Endereco`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente")
private List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Por isso:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();
```

E então, você pode eliminar essa linha:

```
enderecoRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
```

A ideia é que as operações de persistência executadas no `Cliente` devem ser cascateadas para todos os `Endereco`s associados. O `CascadeType.ALL` é um valor curinga que representa a junção de todas as operações do `CascadeType` (`PERSIST`, `REMOVE`, `REFRESH`, `MERGE` e  `DETACH`).

Quando um `Cliente` for persistido (tanto inclusão quanto alteração), deletado, relido do banco de dados ou retirado do gerenciamento do `EntityManager`, o mesmo deve acontecer com todos os `Endereco`s a ele vinculado. Logo, usa-se o `CascadeType.ALL`.

Quanto ao `orphanRemoval = true`, é para eliminar `Endereco`s que não pertençam a nenhum `Cliente`. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90824/132).

Sem fazer uso do `Cascade`, salvar as entidades uma a uma como você estava tentando fazer seria complicado uma vez que há (e está correto em haver) referências cíclicas entre elas, pois o relacionamento é bidirecional.

Coloque também o `CascadeType.PERSIST` aqui:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cidade_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Cidade cidade;
```

Isso ocorre porque quando o endereço for salvo, a cidade a que ele se refere também deve ser salva. Ou então, deixe o `CascadeType.PERSIST` de lado e certifique-se que a instância de `Cidade` escolhida já existe antes de salvar o endereço para evitar duplicatas.

Answer (score 2):

`TransientPropertyValueException`. Isso acontece porque uma ou mais instâncias de `Cidade` não estão sendo administradas  no momento da persistência (i.e., a cidade está *detached*).

As solução para o problema depende da situação do relacionamento:

1. Caso você deseje persistir novas cidades, pode fazé-lo manualmente antes de persistir o endereço:

   ```
   // Assumindo um repositório que salve as cidades
   cidadeRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(c1, c2));
   ```
2. Caso as cidades já existam no banco - e você possui os respectivos ids - a solução ideal seria obter referências administradas e associá-las aos novos endereços:

   ```
   // Assumindo que você está usando JPA
   Cidade mc1 = entityManager.getReference(Cidade.class, c1.getId()); 
   Cidade mc2 = entityManager.getReference(Cidade.class, c2.getId());
   e1.setCidade(mc1);
   e2.setCidade(mc2);
   ```
3. Caso você sempre queira que cidades vinculadas sejam persistidas junto a um endereço (i.e., deseja persistir em cascata), há também uma anotação própria para fazer isso.

   ```
   // No corpo de endereço
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name="cidade_id")
   private Cidade cidade;
   ```

Pensando em um banco de dados devidamente normalizado, em que não existem entradas repetidas na tabela Cidade, a opção número 2 me parece ser a mais correta.

Se a cidade está vindo diretamente de um *input* no usuário, e as cidades não são fixas / alimentadas previamente no *database* (uma modelagem não muito boa para o problema na minha opinião), você precisará escrever uma lógica para verificar se a cidade em questão já existe no banco (e.g., um `SELECT` pelo nome da cidade) e só então decidir se você deve carregar a referência existente ou persistir a nova cidade.

Answer (score -1):

Só inverter e salvar primeiramente o cliente e depois o endereço:
enderecoRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
clienteRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(cli1));

trocar para:

```
clienteRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(cli1));
```

enderecoRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));